# Pycharm does not type hint after dataframe concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, type-hinting

If I want to concatenate 2 dataframes into 1:

```
X_all = pd.concat(objs = [X_train, X_test], axis=0) # type: pd.DataFrame
X_all.fillna(X_all.mean(), inplace = True)
```

Even if I tell pycharm of the type `pd.Dataframe` in comment, on the second line it will still not type hint `.fillna` and I still get the warning: `Unresolved attribute reference 'fillna' for class 'type' less... (⌘F1)`

How can I make pycharm recognize that it is a dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type hint is wrong. It should be `pd.DataFrame`, not `pd.Dataframe` (capital `F`).

```
X_all = pd.concat(objs = [X_train, X_test], axis=0)  # type: pd.DataFrame
```

In Python 3.6+ you can also use native type hinting:

```
X_all: pd.DataFrame = pd.concat(objs = [X_train, X_test], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to do:

```
X_all = pd.concat(objs = [X_train, X_test], axis=0)
assert isinstance(X_all, pd.DataFrame)
X_all.fillna(X_all.mean(), inplace = True)
```